# SpringBoot 2 migration ConfigurationProperties Failed to bind property to String[]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ldap

I just migrate from Spring boot 1.5.8 to 2.0.0

I solved most of migration errors, but I have no idea for this:

```
@Configuration
public class LdapConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ldap")
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        return new LdapContextSource();
    }

    @Bean(name = "ldapTemplate")
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate(ContextSource contextSource) {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }
}
```

My custom values (all variables are var env property, this is why the separator is "_"):

```
LDAP_URLS=ldaps://ldap-url.com:636/
```

Error :

```
Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'ldap.urls' to java.lang.String[]:

    Reason: Unable to get value for property urls

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

looks like it can't bind my string value ldap.urls to String[], I tried with 2 values in my property separated by coma.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try with ldap.urls instead of LDAP_URLS in your application.properties

Comment: all variables are var env property, this is why the separator is "_", I have no application.properties. It works for my all other values

Comment: Ah ok! Have you tried the array way? Look here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0

Comment: Thanks It tried this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0#lists-1) With LDAP_URLS_0 I have the same error, with LDAP_URLS_1 I have this :`Binding to target [Bindable@206aa34b type = java.lang.String[], value = 'provided', annotations = array<Annotation>[[empty]]] failed:

    Property: ldap.urls[1]
    Value: ldaps://ldap-url:636/
    Origin: System Environment Property "LDAP_URLS_1"
    Reason: The elements [ldap.urls[1]] were left unbound.`

Comment: Even when you put  LDAP_URLS_0 you got the same error? "The elements [ldap.urls[0]] were left unbound."? Note that I changed the 1 to a 0 in the error message.

Comment: No sorry with LDAP_URLS_0 I have the initial error : `Failed to bind properties under 'ldap.urls' to java.lang.String[]`

Comment: Maybe you found a bug in Spring Boot 2 :P

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will wait here for spring boot team before opening an issue

Comment: It is related to that particular LdapContextSource as I can't reproduce the problem with a vanilla example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Spring Boot can't bind to an array that is cloned. I've raised [#12478](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12478) as I believe this is a regression in the new binder in 2.0.

Edit: this is now fixed as of Spring Boot 2.0.1