# spring boot: unable to bind yaml list objects

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to bind a list of POJO by yaml properties file but I was no luck to get it work. 
My `application.yml` has the following lines:

```
printer:
  printers:
    - deviceNo: abc
      key: 123
```

And `PrinterProperties` like this:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "printer")
class PrinterProperties {
    var printers: List<Printer> = listOf()
}
```

But the field `printers` was not poputated with the `application.yml`value.

There was a [samilar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766660/spring-boot-2-x-list-binding-issues)

I pushed a demo to a [github repository](https://github.com/amit-gshe/yaml-list-binding-demo.git) to demostrate this problem.

Comment: I converted the POJO from kotlin to [java](https://github.com/amit-gshe/yaml-list-binding-demo/tree/java) and it works now

Comment: @Aymen, re. your suggested edit: Please, Spring Boot is not part of Java EE. It's part of Spring!

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Spring Boot docs at [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) page, you can bind properties like that in your example as long they accomplish one of this conditions:

1) The class property has a setter

2) It's initialized with a mutable value.

`listOf()` will give you an unmutable value therefore it won't work.

Hope it helped! :)

Comment: I tried: `class PrinterProperties(var printers: List<Printer> = mutableListOf())`, but it not works also.

Comment: You maybe could try a couple of things:

- Removing the default value for the list and adding a setter method.
- Initalizing the list with a `new ArrayList<Printer>()` instead.
- Verifying your Printer class has fields that match in name with those in the yaml definition.
 
Here you have a simple [example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/) that may be useful.

Comment: There was a [samilar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766660/spring-boot-2-x-list-binding-issues)

Answer (score 1):

From Andy Wilkinson's advice: the POJO should have a default constructor. So I changed the POJO with:

```
class Printer {
    var deviceNo: String? = null
    var key: String? = null
}
```

and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
printer:
  printers:
    - 
      deviceNo: abc
      key: 123
```

Your yaml file should like this.